# How to redirect https request from one port to another

Tags: apache, redirect, server, vpn

I have a VPS host that handles a subdomain (gate.domain.eu). 
Right now I have a secondary machine in a private network connected to VPN running a gitlab instance. Using  vpn,and port forwarding, i managed to bring  that gitlab instance to https://gate.domain.eu:8443. 
How can I configure the apache server that it will point another subdomain eg(gitlab.domain.eu) to https://gate.domain.eu:8443?

The ideea is that a user should access gitlab trough gitlab.domain.eu.

I configured DNS server for gitlab.domain.eu and configured apache virtual host as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin me@mydomain.com
    ServerName gitlab.domain.eu
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    # setup the proxy
    <Proxy *>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPass / https://gate.domain.eu:8443/
    ProxyPassReverse / https://gate.domain.eu:8443/
</VirtualHost>
```

When accessing gitlab.domain.eu I get:
"Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request."